# Excel formula sumproduct needs optimization

Tags: excel, performance, optimization

I am using SUMPRODUCT to summarize the vacation days for all employees for each month. My formula looks like this:

```
       =SUMPRODUCT((Cal!$B$4:$B$160=Summary!$B8)*
       ((Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="VC")+
       (Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="SK")+
       (Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="TR")+
       ((Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="HVC")/2)+
       ((Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="HSK")/2)+
       ((Cal!$C$4:$ND$160="HTR")/2))*
       (Cal!$D$3:$ND$3>=$E$4)*
       (Cal!$D$3:$ND$3<=$F$4))
```

The vacation days are entered by the employees in sheet Cal and the formula is in sheet Summary. Both sheets are part of the same workbook.

This formula runs for number of employees * months in the year and has slowed down my excel sheet considerably.
Can you please suggest how can I optimize it?
P.S. I cannot use SUMIFS as the values I am counting - VC, SK, etc. are non-numeric

Comment: is the only one employee per row, and no duplicates?

Comment: @ScottCraner Can't you use { } to create an array of values to consider here? Or is that only for `SUMIF`?

Comment: @urdearboy yes and if we can narrow the row we can use a couple COUNTIFS() to do what is wanted.

Comment: What is Summary!$B8 and how does it relate to Cal!$B$4:$B$160? What is in E4 and F4, what worksheet are they on and how do they relate to Cal!$D$3:$ND$3?

Comment: I'm not even sur I know how that works since the lateral calculation cycle is between Cal!C:ND in one section and between Cal!D:ND in another. Mismatched calculation ranges tend to throw #VALUE! errors.

Comment: @ScottCraner - how would you propose diving half of the count by 2?

Comment: @Jeeped count the wholes twice and divide the result by 2.

Comment: Good point! The criteria array could just double up on the wholes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Cal!$C$3:$ND$3,">=" & $E$4,Cal!$C$3:$ND$3,"<=" & $F$4,INDEX(Cal!C:ND,MATCH(Summary!$B8,Cal!B:B,0),0),{"VC","SK","TR","VC","SK","TR","HVC","HSK","HTR"}))/2
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. I used the formula and it saved a tonn of calculating time - from 2 minutes to 6 seconds! Can you pls tell me what are you doing in this part - INDEX(Cal!C:ND,MATCH(Summary!$B8,Cal!B:B,0),0)?

Comment: That returns the correct row as an array so we only iterate through that one row and not the whole area.